# Migrating Work Items from TFS 2017 to VSTS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have to move work items from TFS 2017 (sand box) to VSTS. Please help me with some better solutions available for the same purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Microsoft excel to migrate work items from TFS2017 to VSTS**. Details steps as below:

1. Create a query to list the work items you want to migrate.
2. Export TFS2017 work items. Create and open an excel file -> Team ribbon -> New List -> Servers -> add -> input TFS2017 URL -> OK -> Close -> select your connection -> select a team project -> connect -> choose the query you created in step1 -> OK.
3. Export VSTS work items. Create and open another excel file -> Team ribbon -> New List -> Servers -> add -> input VSTS URL -> OK -> Close -> select a team project -> connect -> choose Input list -> OK.
4. Migrate work items from TFS2017 to VSTS. Copy the items in step2 to the excel file instep3.
5. Click Publish on excel.

#### Note:

- please make sure the two excel files has the same columns orders. You can adjust order and display items in Choose Columns.

[image]

- TFS has some work item type which are different from VSTS, you must change the WIT before publish to VSTS. Such as TFS has Test Plan and Test Suite WIT, you need to change the type as the type which exist in your VSTS project.

There has a document [connect team projects from a worksheet](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/connect/connect-team-projects#connect-from-a-worksheet-or-project-plan) you can refer.

Comment: Perfect..Thanks Marina..