# Migrate Workitems from local TFS into VSTS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm migrating our local TFS to VSTS (Cloud TFS). Everything worked fine so far, but now I want to migrate all the existing workitems to the VSTS. 
I have searched the internet for a solution and found some articles. They suggested to use some CMD-Line Tools to migrate workitems from TFS, but unfortunately, all of them threw some error messages.

Does anyone have a quick and safe way to migrate the workitems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFS has three options for scoping and scaling data - deployments, team project collections, and team projects. Team projects are used to encapsulate the assets of individual software projects, including source code, **work items**, and so on.

- If you don't mind **losing work item history**, you could  just pull
  over work items,  **using Excel**. Details steps please  refer this
  blog- -[Migrating TFS Work Items to a new Team Project using Excel 
  (TFS/VSO/VSTS)](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2016/05/20/Migrating-work-items-to-VSTS-with-custom-fields-using-TFS-Integration-Platform) or this thread-
  -[Migrating Work Items from TFS 2017 to VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779755/migrating-work-items-from-tfs-2017-to-vsts)
- If you have **no work item customisation**, then [OpsHub](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility) is also an
  option.
- If you **have work item customisation** and need keeping histroy ,
  then you are going to have to use [TFS Integration Platform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Willy-PSchaub.TeamFoundationServerIntegrationToolsMarch2012Relea).

You could also use some [customize powershell script](https://github.com/Jvodapalli/TFSWorkitemMigration)  or 3-party tool such as   [VSTS Sync Migration Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration#overview)  for migrating WI with attachments.

More ways and detail explanation please have a look at *jessehouwing's* answer in this question: [How to migrate work items from TFS to VS Team Services (VS Online)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446325/how-to-migrate-work-items-from-tfs-to-vs-team-services-vs-online)

Comment: *Daniel*  is right, if you are working with *TFS 2017 Update 1/ Update 2* , the recommend and clean solution is using [**TFS Database Import Service**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/migration-overview). Sorry for miss this point.

Answer (score 3):

The best option (which I'm surprised Patrick-MSFT didn't mention) is a [direct TFS import to VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/migration-overview).

As long as you're on a supported version of TFS, you can just take your Team Project Collection and have it directly imported into VSTS, with full fidelity migration of all data, including work items.

Comment: I have an old TFS 2010. Can I upgrade locally to a trial version of TFS 2017, so I can migrate to VSTS?