# How to clone a VSTS project/workspace locally?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We have a project/workspace setup in Visual Studio Team Services online.  I would like to get a local backup of the workspace and project with all of its artifacts (attachments, Wiki notes and attachments, etc.).

Would a local version of TFS pointed to VSTS online clone the epics, features and stories locally?  This is what I really need.

What is the process to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can not clone the whole contents of a team project, but clone the source code from version control system (Git or TFVC) is possible.

- If you are using **Git** as VCS, you can use below command to clone the VSTS git repo:

  ```
  git clone <repo URL>
  ```

  And you can also refer [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/clone?tabs=visual-studio) to clone a VSTS git repo via VS.
- If you are using **TFVC** as VCS, you can map TFVC repo locally in VS. Detail steps you can refer [Develop and share your code in TFVC using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs).

Seems you also want to migrate WIT from TFS to VSTS. You can refer these related posts: [Migrate Workitems from local TFS into VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46050215/migrate-workitems-from-local-tfs-into-vsts/46051761#46051761) and [Migrating Work Items from TFS 2017 to VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779755/migrating-work-items-from-tfs-2017-to-vsts).

Besides, you can also refer the document [Migrate data from TFS to VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migration-overview).

Comment: I need the project plan cloned.  What if I had a local TFS running - can I point it to VSTS online - would it import the contents?

Comment: I added the part for migrate work items from TFS to VSTS. You can refer the detail steps in the related links.