# archive TFS project to hard drive

Tags: tfs, git-tfs

I am trying to make sense of TFS projects and figure out ways to export/backup/archive them.

Lets just consider I have an OnPremis TFS project (TFS 2015).

When I use the [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) tool:

1. will it export all work-items?
2. in what format will the
   exported work-items be on my hard drive? (XML, JSON, custom
   DB-Fromat?)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: No. `git-tfs` is a source code migration tool. It only concerns itself with source code repositories. It is not a "backup" or "archival" tool. What is your actual goal here? What is the purpose of the "backups" you want to create? Are you trying to move to a different platform?

Comment: We just want to pull out all TFS data and put them into an archive (with all information included, e.g. work-items). Later we may decide to migrate it to Azure DevOps.

Comment: You already have an archive: the tfs database.

Comment: I suppose the tfs database carries all data across multiple projects in multiple db-collections. Or is all data for one project neatly decoupled in one db-collection or database that is easy to export and I can walk away with my USB drive? (hard to imagine)

Comment: **Why** do you want to be able to *walk away with my USB drive*? You can't export anything at the level of granularity you're looking for. So I'm trying to find out what you hope to accomplish with the data so I can give you a better answer than "Nope, can't do it".

Comment: Thanks for your patience :-) A customer wants to get rid of his On-Premise Team Foundation Server; some TFS projects have to be migrated to Azure DevOps immediatly (here I would use the [azure-devops-migration-tools](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools)), and some need to archived (with the option to migrate them later to DevOps). For each project, pulling all data and artifacts out TFS and into a readable text based format would give the customer a sense of peace. As far as I understand from your answers, there is no common export format for each project -besides the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will it export all work-items?

Just like Daniel said, *[git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) is a source code migration tool. It only concerns itself with source code repositories.*

You can check the scope of this git-tfs tool: [Use git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs#use-git-tfs). There is no such command line is used for work-item.

So, this tool could not be used to export all work-items to hard drive.

> in what format will the exported work-items be on my hard drive? (XML,
>   JSON, custom DB-Fromat?)

The format of the exported work item could be diverse. It depend on which format you need.

For example, we could export work item with witadmin command-line tool in the format XML:

```
witadmin exportwitd /collection:http://AdventureWorksServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:AdventureWorks /f:myworkitems.xml /n:myworkitem
```

This command exports the definition for `myworkitem` to the file, `myworkitems.xml`.

Check the document [Export the definition of a WIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=tfs-2018&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) for some more details.

Besides, we could also export the work-item to the excel/csv, even we could convert it Json format, [Export Visual Studio Team Services Work Items Using PowerShell](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/export-visual-studio-team-services-work-items-using-powershell).

BTW, To migrate work item on TFS to Azure Devops, you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779755/migrating-work-items-from-tfs-2017-to-vsts) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46050215/migrate-workitems-from-local-tfs-into-vsts).

Hope this helps.